# Counting the number of functions on a 4-element set whose composite with itself maps 1 to 2

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and let $F$ be the sets of all functions from $S$ to $S$.

How many functions exist such that $(f \circ f)(1) = 2$?

How many functions exist such that $(f \circ f)(1) = 2$, and $f$ is onto?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem really, any hints to help me count how many of these functions exist? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $f(f(1))= 2$ then $f(1)\not=1$. Hence $[f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4)]$ could be 
$$[2,2,?,?],\;[3,?,2,?],\;[4,?,?,2].$$
For the first question we can replace any ? with $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$.

For the second question note that any onto function from $S$ to $S$ is a bijection!

Comment: so there are 48 ways?

Answer (score 1):

Count them. It's as simple as that.

For the first problem, count how many function from $S$ to $S$ are there which satisfy one of the following conditions:

- $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=2$;
- $f(1)=3$ and $f(3)=2$;
- $f(1)=4$ and $f(4)=2$.

After this, try to solve the second problem.

Comment: So would there only be 3 for the first question? because f(1) can only map to either 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: @MattyS11 Not at all! There are several functions such that $f(1)=2$, not just one.

Comment: okay, so im trying to think about this. if i map $f(1) = 2$, then $f(2)$ must $= 2$. So then can i define $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ to be whatever I want, since they dont have influence on the output of $f(f(1))$. So thats $16$ possible choices, or $1*1*4*4$.. So I do that for $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ as well, so is there $48$ possible functions?

Comment: @MattyS11 It's less than that, since you are counting some functions several times. For instance, the constant function $2$ was counted $3$ times.

Comment: I see. So I think im still correct that when i map $f(1) = 2$, and $f(2)  = 2$, there are $4 \choose 1$ ways for both $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ to be counted. But when I map $f(1) = 3$, and so $f(3) = 2$, does that mean there are now only 3 ways to count $f(2)$ and $f(4)$? Doing it this way, I get 38 functions.

Comment: @MattyS11 I only got $37$ functions, using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: So we dont exclude whichever numbers we picked for the other values once we switch the mapping of $f(1)$? I.E if we map $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 2$, $f(4)$ will still have $4$ possibilities after we map $f(1) = 3$? Wouldn't we only have $3$?

Comment: @MattyS11 I'm sorry: I made a mistake. Not in my answer, but after. in the comments. There's no need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle since the conditions are disjoint (in particular, I was wrong when I asserted that the constant function $2$ satisfies all of them; it satisfies only the first one). The answer is $48$, because $48=3\times16$ and, for each condition, there are $16(=4\times4)$ functions satisfying it.